# How to clear a filtered input field in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to clear an input field that is being filtered in Angular?

```
<input type='text' ng-model='abc' ng-pattern='\[a-z]\' required>
```

I can clear $scope.abc and reset the form field status flags but if the input field value does not match the pattern, then the ng-model is actually already empty and clearing does not clear the field.

I don't want to reference the DOM.  Besides making a custom directive, can anyone think of a way to clear a mismatched input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very clear what the "clear" means for your app, but when an `<input>` field has an invalid value, Angular sets the associated `ngModel` value to `undefined`.
Thus, the easiest way to clear a field would be to set the associated `ngModel` to undefined, **but** this won't work if the `ngModel` is already undefined.

The reason it won't work is that Angular won't be able to detect a change in the model (since it was already `undfined`) and will fail to update the fields value.

A possible work-around would be to temporarily set the value of the `ngModel` to something else (e.g. `null`) and then to `undefined`.
Still, for Angular to be able to pick the change the modifications should happen in different diget cycles. This can be achieved using `$timeout`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="abc" ng-pattern="/[a-z]/" required />
<input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="clearField()" />

$scope.clearField = function () {
    if ($scope.abc !== undefined) {
        /* No need for the "hack", since the 
         * associated model wasn't undefined */
        $scope.abc = undefined;
    } else {
        /* The associated model was undefined:
         * We need to change it to something else first */
        $scope.abc = null;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.abc = undefined;
        });
    }
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wN7cW/)**.

---

BTW, if in the context of your app, `null` can be used for denoting an "empty" field, then the above work-around is  ot even necessary; you can set the associated model to `null` (or `''` or whatever works for you) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. However in my case it doesn't seem to work. I need to see why there is a difference.

Comment: What is "your case" ? Why don't you share the code or better yet preper a fiddle to demonstrate the problem, so we can find the issue. Although I can't really think of a reason, why this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Okay, the hack worked.  Thank you.  The reason I couldn't get it to work in the first place is because I was trying to set null and undefined to an object rather than the members of the object.  Once I broke it out, it worked great.

Comment: One question that I have is if you call $scope.apply() instead of using $timeout, is that too soon following setting to null?

Comment: If you are already in the middle of a $digest loop (which will be the case if the function is triggered from an `ngClick` for example) then calling `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` will throw an error.